# Segmentation fault caused by SIMD gather?

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx2

My project uses SIMD gather for accelerating table lookup. The following is a simplified version, but enough for stating the issue I encountered.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

alignas(32) static int a[256][8] = { 0 };

int main(){
    // initialize 32 bytes (as a __m256i)
    int *s = (int*)_mm_malloc(32, 4);
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        s[i] = i;

    __m256i *t = (__m256i*)s;
    // do table lookup task using SIMD gather
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        int *addr = a[i % 256];
        t[0] = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(addr, t[0], 4);
    }

    // print out the result
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        printf("%d ", s[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Compile and Execution

```
user@server:~/test$ g++ -O3 -mavx2 gather.cpp 
user@server:~/test$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Actually, there is an alternative version using SIMD shuffle with __m128i, which works normally. Does anyone has idea?

Comment: You should [edit] your post to make your code snippet into a [mcve]. Your current code doesn't compile, as it omits the initialization values for `a`.

Comment: Thanks. I re-edited the code.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, g++ 9.3.0, cannot confirm segmentation fault, output is >0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: What is your processor type?

Comment: It is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz

Comment: I tried again. g++ 9.2.0 report segmentation fault, while g++ 7.3.0 does not.

Comment: `int *addr = a[i % 256];` - You want to initialize a pointer with a contents of the `a` array? Wouldn't this result in a pointer that points to an unspecified address? (You initialize only `a[0][0]`.)

Comment: Are you sure you have to manually trigger use of SIMD instructions? I'm pretty sure, today's compilers do a great job resolving loops into SIMD instructions on their own, given they are properly instructed by compilation flags.

Comment: @user9985127, run it in a debugger and tell us the instruction it seg faulted on, also post the assembly listing for main().  I ran your code in VC++ with a few different permutations, and saw no errors.

Also, it sounds like you can't repro in g++ 7.3.0 - it would be useful to dump the assembly for the working and non-working versions and compare them.  We can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_mm_malloc (size_t size, size_t align)` - you're only aligning by 4, then doing an alignment-required dereference of a `__m256i*`.  Presumably that segfaults when `_mm_malloc(32, 4)` happens to return memory that isn't aligned by 32.

Just use `_mm256_set_epi32(7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);` like a normal person, or `alignas(32)` a local array that you can init in a loop.  (And/or you can use `_mm256_loadu_si256` to do an unaligned load).

You *could* fix your code by using `_mm_malloc(32,32)`, but don't.   It's very silly to dynamically allocate (and then leak) a single 32 byte object that you only want for local use.

---

#### Prefer shuffle over gather when all the data comes from one or two 32-byte chunks

An 8-element gather costs about as much as 8 scalar or vector loads, in terms of cache accesses, plus some work for other execution units.  (https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/).  Gather doesn't get more efficient when multiple elements come from the same cache line, unfortunately.

In your case you don't even need a shuffle, just a 32-byte load from a part of `a[][]`.

`int *addr = a[i % 256];` gets a pointer to a 32-byte aligned `int [8]`, from which you can `_mm256_load_si256((const __m256i*)addr)`.  That gives you the elements in the 0..7 native order you want.

If you did want orders other than 0..7, use AVX2 `vpermd`  ([`_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=vpermd&expand=5236,3543,2983,4201&techs=AVX2)) with the same shuffle-control vector constant you were using as gather indices.

Comment: After lots of attempts, I think this is the correct answer. Thanks.